# Sylius Resource and Doctrine Filter

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, sylius, sylius-resource

I'm new in Sylius and trying to extend it for my business. I'm currently facing an issue on admin part that I don't know how to solve.

I've an Basket entity which is One-To-One related with the Sylius Product entity:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_basket")
 */
class Basket implements ResourceInterface, BasketInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product\Product", inversedBy="basket", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $product;
}
```

I created this relation to be able to deal with Order Management of Sylius much easier. I don't want to mix Basket and Product objects in my business, so I created a Doctrine filter to exclude Basket items from Products:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Doctrine\Filter;

use App\Entity\Product\Product;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Filter\SQLFilter;

class ProductFilter extends SQLFilter
{

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function addFilterConstraint(ClassMetadata $targetEntity, $targetTableAlias)
    {
        if($targetEntity->getName() !== Product::class) {
            return '';
        }

        return "$targetTableAlias.id not in (select product_id from app_basket)";
    }

}
```

On the admin products page, everything is great, I don't have the baskets. But, if I go the the Basket admin index page, I have the following error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Entity of type 'App\Entity\Product\Product' for IDs id(4) was not
>   found").

This is because of the grid I use. I want to display the name of the product included in the basket:

```
sylius_grid:
    grids:
        app_admin_basket:
            driver:
                name: doctrine/orm
                options:
                    class: App\Entity\Basket\Basket
            fields:
                id:
                    type: string
                    label: sylius.ui.id
                product.name:
                    type: string
                    label: sylius.ui.name
```

To retrieve the basket.product.name, the generated query is querying directly to the product table instead of the basket one:

```
SELECT t0.code AS code_1, t0.created_at AS created_at_2, t0.updated_at AS updated_at_3, t0.enabled AS enabled_4, t0.id AS id_5, t0.variant_selection_method AS variant_selection_method_6, t0.average_rating AS average_rating_7, t0.main_taxon_id AS main_taxon_id_8, t9.id AS id_10, t9.product_id AS product_id_11 
--problem here
FROM sylius_product t0 
LEFT JOIN app_basket t9 ON t9.product_id = t0.id 
WHERE t0.id = 4 
--Doctrine SQL FIlter
AND ((t0.id not in (select product_id from app_basket)));
```

I've also the same behavior if a get this in a twig template :

```
{{ basket.product.name }}
```

With a fetch="EAGER" annotation I don't have the error but the targeted entity still not reflect what I want.

Is there a way to force Sylius Resource to pass through basket entity first and not directly to the embedded entity?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sylius_grid:
    grids:
        app_admin_basket:
            driver:
                name: doctrine/orm
                options:
                    class: App\Entity\Basket\Basket
            fields:
                id:
                    type: string
                    label: sylius.ui.id
                product.name:
                    type: twig
                    label: sylius.ui.name
                    path: .
                    options:
                        template: thetemplate.html.twig
```

The `path: .` property gives you access to the whole entity instead of a specific property. You should then be able to access it using `data.product.name` in the twig template.

You could also [try this](https://github.com/Sylius/SyliusGridBundle/blob/master/docs/field_types.md), altho I haven't tested it:

```
sylius_grid:
    grids:
        app_admin_basket:
            driver:
                name: doctrine/orm
                options:
                    class: App\Entity\Basket\Basket
            fields:
                id:
                    type: string
                    label: sylius.ui.id
                product.name:
                    type: string
                    label: sylius.ui.name
                    path: product.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Your filter will always prevent fetching the basket's product.
You can try to disable it at least for this request: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/filters.html#disabling-enabling-filters-and-setting-parameters